# OS X: Comparing two images

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode7, nsdata, nsimage

I'm trying to implement a way to compare two images but I'm testing my and comparing the same image to make sure is working but doesn't work. here is may code:

```
NSImage *file = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSData *imgDataOne = [file TIFFRepresentation];
NSData *imgDataTwo = [file TIFFRepresentation];

if (imgDataOne == imgDataTwo)
{
    NSLog(@"is the same image");
}
```

The if is never true. Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or if another way to compare the images?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: `if ([imgDataOne isEqual:imgDataTwo])`? You're comparing pointers.

Comment: Could you hash each image?

Comment: @Larme using isEqual or isEqualToData works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIFFRepresentation` will return a new NSData object. Comparing these objects using the `==` operator will always return false because these are two different objects.

NSData has `isEqualToData` method to test if these two NSData objects contain the same binary data.